# How to automatically limit pressing a key limited times with Python?

Tags: python, keyboard, pyautogui

Maybe it's a stupid question. I need to automate some actions with Python on my work. For this purpose I use PyAutogui and keyboard packages. But i have a problem:

1. In one part of my working interface I have a different number of cells. In each cell I need to press ENTER -> KEYDOWN -> ENTER.
2. For transition between cells the KEYDOWN is used. So, if I have two cells, I need to press: ENTER -> KEYDOWN -> ENTER in the cell, then KEYDOWN for jumping to another cell and next  ENTER -> KEYDOWN -> ENTER in next cell.

[image]

But there is a problem. How to automatically stop exactly on the last cell? The amount of cells is varies in different cases.

Thank you.

`import pyautogui
    import time

    def cell_filler(number_of_cells = 10, last_cell = False):
        while number_of_cells > 0:
            if last_cell:
                pyautogui.press('enter')
                pyautogui.press('down')
                pyautogui.press('enter')
                break
            pyautogui.press('enter')
            pyautogui.press('down')
            pyautogui.press('enter')
            pyautogui.press('down') #  jumping to another cell
            number_of_cells -= 1
            time.sleep(0.5)`

How can i find `last_cell`?

Comment: This is a good question, but you need to also add your code so we can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui

#You can use SHIFT+Command+4 to get the XY co-ordinate on a Mac

pyautogui.click(230, 70) #to click into the box
pyautogui.typewrite("hello world")
pyautogui.typewrite(["enter"])
```

this is only the first part of what you want to do. to keep doing the rest just read this documentation https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html